# How to include and exclude patterns in one regex

Tags: c#, regex

#### Snippet

Let's say there are two regexes - one with patterns that are good and another with patterns that are wrong:

```
var allowed = new Regex("^(a.*|b.*)$");
var disallowed = new Regex("^(aa|bb|.*c)$");
```

When this snippet is run:

```
var cases = new[] {"a", "aa", "aaa", "b", "bb", "bbb", "ac", "bc", "ad", "ad"};
foreach (var c in cases)
    Console.WriteLine($"{c}: {allowed.IsMatch(c) && !disallowed.IsMatch(c)}");
```

It works.

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to merge those two regexes into one?
2. Would it be a better design to create a set of regexes and enumerate over them to test if the input string matches any of the *good* patterns and none of the *bad* patterns?

Comment: [`^(?>a(?!a$).*|b(?!b$).*)(?<!c)$`](https://regex101.com/r/yB2qY2/1). Good regex patterns are manual work. Do not automate automations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple put them together using a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!^(aa|bb|.*c)$)^(a.*|b.*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mX8iY4/1)

You can shorten this regex by only specifying the parts you don't want. The rest should match:

```
(?!^(aa|bb|.*c)$)^.*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mX8iY4/2)

Using this you don't have the problem that you try to combine including and excluding regexes in one regex.

And finally you can try this regex:

```
^(a|b)(?!\1$).*(?<!c)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mX8iY4/3)

Comment: Oh I see that Wiktor Stribiżew posted a comment that shows the same idea like my last regex 3 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your second question: Depends on whether you want maintainability or speed.

If your rule sets are subject to constant change then I would think multiple sets would be easier to maintain, each set being specific enough to name them.

If you're looking for speed, let's say your parsing long documents or what have you, then a single one would be faster.  Making them static readonly and then the difference is very negligible and MUCH, MUCH faster (around 10 times faster).  The 'static readonly' really only applies when you move the logic out into a separate method, you wouldn't want to recreate the regex every call.

However, if you are looking  both ... do it in code!  There are many ways to write this, but they all seem to be around the same speed and that is over 6 times faster than the compiled regex.  I believe this would be easier to maintain even without the comments but with a few comments it becomes very clear.

```
private bool IsAllowed(string word)
{
  // empty string or whitespace is allowed
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word)) return true;

  // any word ending in the letter c is not allowed
  if (word[word.Length - 1] == 'c') return false;

  // any length that is not two letter is allowed
  if (word.Length != 2) return true;

  // allow anything except aa or bb
  return word != "aa" && word != "bb";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically exclude regexes are very hard to write, even more so when combined with including matches. You could try using negative lookahead/lookbehind to do this.

Typically even when possible, the result is not very maintainable. Having seperate regexes for include and exclude is almost always better from an "I want to understand this code when I come back to it in 3 months" point of view.

You can combine the "good" patterns into a single regex - this should always be possible. It might even improve performance, as the regex compiler can optimise over all the patterns at once. But if there are a lot of them it then it may make maintenance more difficult - no one wants to read a 200 character regex.

So in summary, seperate regexes for include and exclude patterns, but smaller numbers of each are better, provided they don't get too complex. You'll have to use your judgement to work out what is best for your individual case.